# How can I "clone" the layout of buffers to a new buffer in Vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Upon setting `scrollbind` for two buffers that are vertically split, and I retain a the same buffer layout in a new tab? Or, a new Vim session?

I would like to avoid the tedious scrolling and matching of rows that are needed for setting a reasonable `scrollbind`.

Had there been a plugin that could "mimic" the current layout in either a new buffer or a new [G]Vim session?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want two tabs with the same files and `scrollbind` set on both? And could you give an example of what is the purpose of your setup?

Comment: I have two buffers side by side (constructed using `vsp`). I would like to create a new buffer that duplicates the current view of such two-parallel-buffers.

Comment: I think that your question would be clearer if [you replace 'buffer' with 'windows'](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/buffers-windows-tabs/). Certainly it is possible to write macros/functions to duplicate some/all of your windows, but maybe there are better solutions than duplicating them, depending on what you are trying to do. Could you explain what is the *purpose* of doing this? In other words, how could this be useful?